# f:convertDateTime displays day and month inversed, and time 1 hour in past

Tags: jsf, datetime, converters

I'm using convertDataTime to convert dates from a database. The problem that arises is that does not display dates correctly:

Example: In the database I have the date `09/10/2013 14:36:57` and it displays `10/09/2013 13:36:57`.

Here is my code:

```
<p:dataTable ...>
                 ...
                 <p:column headerText="Data of sale">
                     <h:outputText value="#{faturaVar.dataEmissao}">
                         <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                     </h:outputText>
                 </p:column>
                 ...
</p:dataTable>
```

Att: I'm using primefaces 3.5, JPA / EJB.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure the tool you use to execute your queries is configured to return dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format? If not sure, do the naive approach and use `SELECT YEAR(date_field), MONTH(date_field), DAY(date_field) FROM yourTable WHERE ...` and verify this.

Comment: The problem is not on the query, because i made a simple test. I print the date before it shows on dataTable, and i get the real date on database.

Comment: How do you print the *real date* before showing it on datatable?

Comment: Create a mthod to show de date like : `<h:outputText value="#{UtilBean.methodToShowData(faturaVar.dataEmissao)}">`. The `methodToShow` only print the given data on the console and return it.

Comment: How have you implemented this method?

Comment: `public Date methodToShow(Date dt)
{
    System.out.println(dt);
    return dt;
}`

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant code there, not in comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38916/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-coldhack)

Answer (score 1):

It is missing the `timezone` attribute in `f:convertDateTime` tag.

**Update**

There might be different timezone between `DB Server` and `Application Server`. Try to use `timezone` attribute in `f:convertDateTime` tag.

```
<f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" timezone="your-time-zone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your managed bean or cdi bean add a method like this

```
 public TimeZone getTimeZone() {
return TimeZone.getDefault();
 }

 in the jsf ui <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{bean.timeZone}" />
```